# How to use std::map of non-wrapped C++ objects in NodeJs native addon

Tags: c++, node.js

I cannot really understand why my addon randomly crashes with:

```
Fatal error in ../deps/v8/src/api.h, line 297
CHECK(allow_empty_handle || that != __null) failed
```

For now I think it could be memory related issue in my code, but I'm not sure if my approach is right.

Here is some code details:

My C++ addon is loaded only once at the start-up of the main NodeJs application. The main application can call several exported functions in my addon. One of these functions (named belowe as 'Initialize') gets an unique id, which is used to find the C++ object (named below as 'MyObject') instance from a globally defined std::map of objects (named below as g_mapObject). If the object with a given key is not found in the map, then 'Initialize' function creates and inserts one into the map, a new instance of that object and then initialize this object. 
The other exported functions are periodically called from the main application. They retrieve an object from the map and operate on it.

In my MyAddon.cc:

```
#include "MyAddon.h"
#include "MyObject.h"

using namespace v8;

std::map<string, MyObject*> g_mapObject;

Handle<Value> MyAddon::Initialize(const Arguments& args) {
    HandleScope scope;

    String::AsciiValue id(args[0]->ToString());    

    // Get the object from g_mapObject and initialize it. 
    // If the object is not found then create and insert it into map.


    return scope.Close(0);
}

Handle<Value> MyAddon:UpdateObjectData1(const Arguments& args) {
    HandleScope scope;

    String::AsciiValue id(args[0]->ToString());

    // Get the object from g_mapObject and update its data

    return scope.Close(0);
}

Handle<Value> MyAddon::UpdateObjectData1(const Arguments& args) {
    HandleScope scope;

    String::AsciiValue id(args[0]->ToString());

    // Get the object from g_mapObject and update its data

    return scope.Close(0);
}
```

Each method is wrapped with uv_mutex_lock/unlock calls, so it is ensured and tested that method calls are sychronized. The fatal error occures in 'initialize' method (but never at its first call).

PS: Just to mention that I use C++11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach was right, but there was a logical bug in implementation.